# Handling Exception for calling multiple store procedure in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 3 store procedures. I have one orchestration store procedure with error handlers with try catch blocks. In each catch block i have logged in custom error to a log table to log the error, and then i call `return()` to exit.

But when I call these 3 store procedure from the orchestration store procedure, if any errors/exceptions are thrown it logs and then exits from that store procedure. It then starts executing the next store procedure.

But in my case if any exception raised in any one of the store procedures in the orchestration store procedure I want it to exit and stop executing the next procedure too. It should then exit out of ORCH_SP.

How can i achieve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORCH_SP()       
RETURN VARCHAR LANGUAGUE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$ {      
    P1();       
    P2();       
    P3();       
} $$;
```

Comment: Made language clearer and formatted code

Answer (score 0):

How about introducing try/catch blocks into ORCH_SP() and checking on the return value from each of the calls to the child SPs to determine whether to re-throw an error if generated (and exit) - or proceed to calling the next SP...The following is a simplified example to roughly illustrate the approach:

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORCH_SP()       
RETURNS VARCHAR LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$ {  
    var return_msg = "";
    try {
        var sp_call = "call P1()";    
        var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sp_call});  
        result.next();
        var return_msg = result.getColumnValue(1);
        if (return_msg!='SUCCESS') {
            throw return_msg;
        } 
        else {
            // call P2() and P3() from here...
            // perhaps in their own try/catch blocks
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return return_msg;
    }
    return return_msg;
} $$;  


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1()       
RETURNS varchar 
LANGUAGE javascript      
AS $$ { 
    var result = "SUCCESS";
    try {
        // comment/uncomment the next line to simulate success/failure
        throw 'naughty naughty';
    }       
    catch (err) {
      result = err;
    }
    return result;
} $$;  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

[Mike has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59832626/9056819) the most straight forward change you can make above, by inspecting the returned values for errors by content. The following is just to add another possible approach.

--

Shown in [some of examples within the Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#logging-an-error-version-2), a procedure can terminate with a thrown error instead of an explicit return.

It is possible to write the underlying procedures (`P1`, `P2`, `P3`) in such a format, where the throw automatically acts as a termination without needing to be caught, and preserves the error context for any direct or indirect CALL:

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1()       
RETURN VARCHAR LANGUAGUE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$ {      
    // (… logic …)

    if (faultyCondition) {

      throw 'p1 failure reason';

    }

} $$;

-- Repeat above pattern for (P2, P3, etc.)
```

Then the calling parent procedure can be written in the following manner, and will cease to execute at any error instead of continuing:

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORCH_SP()       
RETURN VARCHAR LANGUAGUE JAVASCRIPT      
AS $$ {
  try {      

    // Note: Add more args / call directly as necessary for real-life use
    function run(call_name) { 
      snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: `CALL $call_name();` }).execute();
    }

    run("P1");       
    run("P2");       
    run("P3");  

    // (… other logic …)

  } catch (err) {

    result = err;

  }

  return result;     

} $$;
```

This pattern is more in line with how error handling is usually implemented with try-catch use and sub-functions.